# Acoustic guitar strings change by time and should i change them?

Tags: acoustic-guitar, strings

I've just knew that the strings of the guitar change sounds over time into a brighter and lighter sound. So I wanted to know if is it necessary to change them between time to time? Or is it OK if I kept them?

And also what's the average time of the string life depending on usage?

Thank you.

Comment: We'd probably all like to know what strings you have that get a brighter sound when they're older.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all changing strings of your guitar depends on usage. For example I have to change my acoustic and electric guitar strings once a month, also playing each of them likely 1 hour per day. When the tune change and when it starts to hurt my fingers, i change them. 
What's more, you should change your strings even if they don't break off. Because they are being oxidated and it may damage your frets if you are using steel strings for a long time.
You might clean your strings with a **dry** linen after done playing. That makes strings a little bit durable.

Answer (score 2):

Also want to add that your strings don't get brighter as they age, in general they sound darker and more dull.

You ought to change them roughly once every month or 2, but it depends on what strings you use and how often you play guitar. If you notice the tone changing, and not for the better, then it's time to change them. The more you play, the more you'll learn about the guitar itself and the more you'll get to know things like this, as it can change between guitars, string sets, different players, etc.